# Strange issue with font on my Jekyll Site

Tags: css, fonts, backtrack-linux

I have this custom made site using Jekyll: http://madhur.github.com/

When I view this site under Backtrack Linux -> Google Chrome(13) , I see the main font as "`Sans Serif - Regular`"

I have specified this under CSS file

```
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida", sans-serif;
```

The same site under Windows 7 -> Google Chrome (13), I see the font as `Lucida Sans Unicode`

What is the reason for this discrepancy ? Is it because Lucida Sans Unicode is already available in Windows but not in Linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Lucida isn't available in Linux, so the browser fallback to "Sans Serif - Regular". This side shows some alternative fonts to use with linux: http://mondaybynoon.com/2007/04/02/linux-font-equivalents-to-popular-web-typefaces/